# OfxEtherDream : where is getNumEtherdream()?

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I use memo's Etherdream addon for Open Frameworks, and I've to compile a source who attemps to call a static function `ofxEtherdream::getNumEtherdream()`, but it doesn't exist.

Do you know where does it come from ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only occurrence of this call I could find was [this one](https://github.com/pach/ofLaserLiveTool/blob/e064509eb17452d2d16f5af6df666e3611d279db/src/ofApp.cpp#L10).
The strange thing is the repo points to memo's library, yet this function (`getNumEtherdream()`) doesn't appear in any of his commits.

My guess is that's been implemented locally and never pushed to a public repository.

Even so, [this line](https://github.com/memo/ofxEtherdream/blob/master/src/ofxEtherdream.cpp#L44) looks promising.

Perhaps you can try to declare

```
int getNumEtherdream();
```

in `ofxEtherdream.h` and try to implement in `ofxEtherdream.cpp` as

```
int ofxEtherdream::getNumEtherdream() {
   return etherdream_dac_count();
}
```

Bare in mind I've never used this addon/library and the above isn't tested, it's just a hunch.

Otherwise, if you're starting with a single device, you can comment out the call and adapt your code to use the first device only at this stage. It doesn't solve your problem, but it's just a pragmatic suggestion to move things forward a bit.

Comment: Yeah ! Just adding the function was not sufficient, i used the whole pach's etherdream and it worked. :)
Thank you !